# Getting started with scalafx?

Tags: scalafx

I'm a casual Scala user; I use the Eclipse-based Scala IDE, and I have never needed to know maven or sbt. I'd like to learn scalafx, but all the instructions are for maven. In the Scala IDE, Scala doesn't recognize my imports. Can someone tell me how to have the IDE recognize the jar file?

I have

- Scala IDE 4.2.0-vfinal-2015-09-25T11:10:29Z-Typesafe
- scalafx_2.12.0-M3-8.0.60-R9.jar
- JavaSE 1.8
- Scala Library container 2.11.7

I tried adding the scalafx jar to my Java build path (Project->Properties doesn't have a Scala build path), and that didn't work, so I don't know what else to try.

Thank in advance!

// ----- Not an answer, too long for a comment, sorry -----

I appreciate the fact that, were I a serious Scala developer, I should learn Maven and SBT. But I'm not.

For the last several years I have taught a course in "Programming Paradigms." This semester I have taught Prolog, Clojure, Haskell, Elm, and a bit of Forth and REBOL. As in the past, I'm ending with Scala, because I think it brings together a lot of the ideas in other languages, and would be a worthy successor to Java. From what I have read, scalafx looks easy to use, and it would have been nice to have the last assignment be a GUI assignment using scalafx.

For any programming language, external factors--IDEs, make equivalents, test frameworks, support groups, etc.--are at least as important as the language itself. Given the amount of material already in the course, I explicitly do not cover any of these external factors, for any of the languages.

Since installing scalafx apparently is not as simple as adding a jar file to Eclipse (which my students already use), in my situation it is simply not worthwhile learning SBT and devoting additional class time to teaching it.

Maybe next year scalafx--or, I guess, the Scala IDE--will have matured to the point that I can use it in my course.

Thanks to everyone for clarifying the situation.

Comment: I understand that I'm not answering your question... but you would be better of learning Maven and/or SBT.

Comment: I do not really use Eclipse for Scala but I was just curious did you add dependencies and it didn't work?

Comment: I'm sorry that SBT isn't a good fit for you - which is a shame, since ScalaFX (and almost all other JVM libraries) assumes that you're using managed dependencies. Going the manual route isn't a viable alternative. Unfortunately, Eclipse's ScalaIDE plugin doesn't (as of V4.2) support SBT, and instead uses it's own, internal build system—hence my suggestion you look at IntelliJ. The good news is that ScalaIDE V4.3 (which was due out last month, but which is a little late) aims to integrate SBT as its build system. So you'll soon be able to use Eclipse, Scala and SBT together in any case...

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer that you wanted, but I would recommend that you go with either *Maven* or *SBT* - preferably the latter, as it is targeted at *Scala* and *Scala* users. The reason for this is quite simple: both systems will manage your dependencies automatically, in a very simple way.

If you decide to manage dependencies manually, then—sooner or later—you're going to be heading for a world of pain. For example, *ScalaFX* may have its own dependencies, which you would have to download and install on your class path, and they may have their own dependencies, etc, etc.

Learning SBT can be a challenge, but it's also very straightforward to do simple projects. For example, the following SBT file (copy to a file called `build.sbt` in your project's root directory) is the minimum for a *ScalaFX* application:

```
name := "myproject"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.60-R9"
```

Just make sure that you're using an up-to-date version of *Java 8* (you'll need *ScalaFX* 2 if you're using *Java* 7).

Also, you might want to try *JetBrain*'s free community edition of *[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)*, with the *Scala* plugin, as an alternative to *Eclipse*. *IntelliJ* supports *Scala* and *SBT* very nicely indeed.

**UPDATE**: Also, I just noticed that you have the *Scala* 2.12 version of *ScalaFX*, but you're using the *Scala* 2.11 compiler. Unfortunately, each version of the compiler requires a matching copy of *Scala* library code. This is yet another reason for using *SBT*. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ScalaFX with students for about a year now both from command line and inside of Eclipse. I use neither sbt nor Maven for that work to keep things simpler for the students. I built a JAR file, much like the one that you have and either use -cp from the command line or add it to the build path (as an external JAR) in Eclipse. Both approaches have worked fine for me. I create and object and have it extend scalafx.application.JFXApp. That runs and pops up a window. It would help to know more about how it isn't working. Does it not compile because elements of ScalaX aren't being found, or does it not run after the compile?

I will also note that at the time of writing this answer, ScalaFX does not yet work for Scala 2.12, which is at the M4 stage.